# How to break out of this for loop: `for (; cin >> A;);`

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, break

```
for (cout << "\nEnter the Sentence now:";
    cin >> Ascii;

cout << "The ascii value of each letter you entered, added to the offset factor is: " 
     << (int)Ascii + RandomNumberSubtract << endl);
```

Comment: WT...why are you doing this?

Comment: I think you need to post more code so that people who want to help you understand what you are doing.

Comment: A for loop executes the next statement, and this is always only 1 thing.  But your 'for loop' is ill formed.  You should look it up, but the hint I will offer is  "for (int i=0; i<56; ++i) { /*do one thing here*/ }

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best advice is don't be clever. Not only do you make it hard for anyone else* to read, understand, and modify your code, you run a real risk of outsmarting yourself.

Thus, don't try to do weird and clever things to implement your loop. Just do things naturally. If they don't *naturally* fit into how `for` or `while` or `do ... while` statements are structured, then just write a generic loop and use `break` statements to deal with leaving the loop. e.g.

```
while (true) {
    // Some stuff
    if (i_should_break_out_of_the_loop) {
        break;
    }
    // Some more stuff
}
```

This is pretty much always better than doing things like torturing the `for` statement in the way you have.

Once you have a clear, easily comprehensible loop, it should be relatively easy to modify it to suit your needs. (or to ask a clearer and more focused question)

*: "anyone else" also includes you three weeks from now, after you've had time for it leave your short term memory.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to turn this loop into a `while` loop. However the following is true whether or not you do:

Just enter an EOF, then the loop will terminate.

How an EOF is input will depend on your OS (and possibly also on your terminal settings). On Linux (under default terminal settings) you get an EOF pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of the line. On Windows, I think it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. On Mac I have no idea.

Of course you could also redirect stdin for your program to come from a file (in which case EOF is — as you would guess — generated at the end of file), or from a pipe (in which case EOF is generated as soon as the writing program closes the pipe).

If the variable `Ascii` is not of type char or string, you may also enter something that cannot be parsed as that variable's data type (e.g. if reading an `int`, anything other than a number will cause the stream to report failure and thus the loop to terminate).

You also might want to add another end condition then *in the loop body* (which in your `for` loop is currently just an empty statement). For example, you might decide that a percent sign should terminate your loop; then you could write (I'm still assuming the type of `Ascii` which you didn't provide is `char`):

```
cout << "\nEnter the Sentence now:";
while(cin >> Ascii)
{
   cout << "The ascii value of each letter you entered, added to the offset factor is: " 
        << (int)Ascii + RandomNumberSubtract << endl);
   if (Ascii == '%')
     break;
}
```

However note that normally `operator<<` skips whitespace; I guess you don't want whitespace skipped. Therefore you probably shouldn't use `operator<<` but `get`; this will also allow you to use the end of line as end condition:

```
cout << "\nEnter the Sentence now:";
while(std::cin.get(Ascii) && Ascii != '\n')
{
   cout << "The ascii value of each letter you entered, added to the offset factor is: " 
        << (int)Ascii + RandomNumberSubtract << endl);
}
```

However in that case, it's better to read the line in one step and then iterate through it:

```
cout << "\nEnter the Sentence now:";
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
for (std::string::iterator it = line.begin; it != line.end(); ++it)
{
  cout << "The ascii value of each letter you entered, added to the offset factor is: " 
        << (int)*it + RandomNumberSubtract << endl;
}
```

Note that in C++11, you can simplify this into

```
cout << "\nEnter the Sentence now:";
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
for (auto ch: line)
{
  cout << "The ascii value of each letter you entered, added to the offset factor is: " 
        << (int)ch + RandomNumberSubtract << endl;
}
```